# MySQL find and replace - add a line break

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

After migrating a website from another system, I have some text that needs a line break between words.

For example, I want to change:

```
ish.nArchipelago
```

into:

```
ish.
Archipelago
```

I am currently using the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'ish.nArchipelago', 'ish.\nArchipelago');
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Is it every occurrence of `<word>.n<word>` or just that specific one?

Comment: for all, thanks. Basically every
`<word>.n<word>`
need to be:
    `<word>.`

   `<word>`

Answer (score 0):

To replace every occurrence of

```
<word>.n<word>
```

with

```
<word>.
<word>
```

use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '\.n', '\.\n');
```

Your query would be:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '\.n', '\.\n');
```

Comment: Thanks you.That's perfect.

Comment: I did but I can't since I haven't yet 15 reputations. That's what the system says. It will be added as soon as I got there. Thank you again.